Proof $X=\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ is not homeomorphic to $B$.
I want to show that the space $B$ is not homeomorphic to the space $X$, where
$$
B:=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}} C_n=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \left\lvert\,\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2+y^2=\frac{1}{n^2}\right.\right\},
$$
The idea is to prove that $X$ is not compact, given that $B$ obviously is. To do this, we cover $\mathbb{R}$ with the open sets
$$
\mathcal{F}_{\mathbb{R}}=\left\{\left(a-\frac{1}{2}, a+\frac{1}{2}\right): a \in \mathbb{Z}\right\} \cup\left\{\left(a+\frac{1}{4}, a+\frac{3}{4}\right): a \in \mathbb{Z}\right\} .
$$
Now we define an open cover for $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ as follows:
$$
\mathcal{F}_{\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}}=\left\{\pi(U): U \in \mathcal{F}_{\mathbb{R}}\right\}
$$
where $\pi$ is the canonical projection. The key point is that we need to show that $\pi\left(a-\frac{1}{2}, a+\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $\pi\left(a+\frac{1}{4}, a+\frac{3}{4}\right)$ are open, i.e., if and only if $\pi^{-1}\left(\pi\left(a-\frac{1}{2}, a+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$ and $\pi^{-1}\left(\pi\left(a+\frac{1}{4}, a+\right.\right.$ $\left.\frac{3}{4}\right)$ ) are open sets in $\mathbb{R}$.
However, we have:
$$
\pi\left(a-\frac{1}{2}, a+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\left\{[y]: y \in\left(a-\frac{1}{2}, a+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right\}=\left\{\{y\}: y \in\left(a-\frac{1}{2}, a+\frac{1}{2}\right) \backslash\{a\}\right\} \cup\{\mathbb{Z}\}
$$
Thus:
$$
\pi^{-1}\left(\pi\left(a-\frac{1}{2}, a+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)=\left(a-\frac{1}{2}, a+\frac{1}{2}\right) \cup \mathbb{Z}
$$
and this is not an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. Meanwhile,
$$
\pi^{-1}\left(\pi\left(a+\frac{1}{4}, a+\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)=\left(a+\frac{1}{4}, a+\frac{3}{4}\right)
$$
which is open in $\mathbb{R}$.
Hence, that particular covering does not work. I have another idea: to cover the real line in the following way: choose very small open sets around the integers, i.e., sets of the form $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$ for each $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, and cover the rest of the line with intervals of the form $(a+\delta,(a+1)-\delta)$ for suitable choices of $\delta$. This way:
$$
\pi^{-1}(\pi(a+\delta,(a+1)-\delta))=(a+\delta,(a+1)-\delta)
$$
since this interval does not contain $a$ itself, and it is clearly open in $\mathbb{R}$. The idea is that when we take the union $\bigcup(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$ and then apply $\pi^{-1}(\pi(\cdots))$, we get a set $W$ that is open in $\mathbb{R}$.
The question now is how to choose $\epsilon$. Once $\epsilon$ is chosen, it is easy to pick $\delta$ appropriately.

You want to prove $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ is not compact?  But it is compact.  It is the same as the unit circle ${ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1}$.

@D_S There is a notational confusion. If you go through the OP’s question, here $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ means collapsing $\mathbb{Z}$ to be a single point (i.e., regarding $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$), not taking the quotient from the equivalence relation $x-y\in\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e., regarding $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},+)$). Both notations are, unfortunately, standard.

Just replace the sets $\pi((a -1/2, a+1/2))$ with their union, which is open.

It doesn’t really matter too much what you choose your $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ to be. As long as $0 < \epsilon \leq 1/2$ and $0 < \delta < \epsilon$, this will work.
